# What is cp in Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages?

Tags: python

I was trying to download pillow from Unofficial Windows
Binaries for Python Extension Packages and there is a `cp` version, what is it?

Do I have to download it or does it come by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cp means CPython - reference implementation of Python written in C.

Probably, it is the version you need, unless you are using some other Python implementation, like PyPy or Jython.

Comment: okay thanks but how to install pillow for my python 2.7 32 bit what is the right version for me

Comment: `pip install http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/tuoh5y4k/Pillow-4.1.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl`
in your windows console